# I've make a player that plays the audio files. I want the player to play a song after it finishes one.. Seeking for help in solving this

Tags: html, audio-player

This is the part that makes a link to the first song.

```
    <html>
    <a href="pelay.html"> Play Song </a>
    </html>
```

This is where the link goes, and plays the audio automatically after clicking the link.

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=file:///C:/Users/Mau%20Mao/Music/music/Change.mp3" />
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I control the player to play the next song?

Comment: You can hardly call that an “audio player” at all IMHO. Look into the HTML5 `audio` element.

Comment: What you're doing is simply redirecting the browser to point to the file, and the built in audio player is playing it. The best way to do it would be to use the HTML5 `audio` element, which I believe has a Javascript callback when the song is finished.

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mUB78/1/

Comment: var songs = ['mysong', 'song2', 'song3'];
var index = 0;
function nextSong(){
    alert('Triggered');
    $('#player').attr('src', songs[index++]);
}
$("#player").bind('ended', nextSong);
$(document).ready(function(){
    nextSong();
});

Can i know, how does the code work?

Answer (score 1):

Because I was asked to explain the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mUB78/4/) [UPDATED] I posted in the comments:

---

```
<audio id="player" controls="true" autoplay="true"></audio>
```

This is the audio player element. This is the part that actually plays the audio. It is rendered by the browser, so can look different depending on the browser and/or OS. In Chrome it looks like this:
[image: Audio Player 1]
Because I have added the `controls` attribute you can see it. If you were to remove the controls attribute you would be able to hear the audio, but could not control any of it. `autoplay` tells the browser to start playing the audio as soon as it loads.

```
var songs = ['song1.mp3', 'song2.mp3', 'song3.mp3'];
```

This defines a new array, called songs, which contains the URLs of three songs. More can be added simply by appending `, 'song4.mp3'` to the last value.

```
var index = 0;
```

This defines a new variable which will contain the number of the song we are on. This means that when the number is equal to `0`, it will play the first entry, `1` for the second and so on (arrays start at 0).

```
function nextSong(){
    alert('Triggered');
    $('#player').attr('src', songs[index++]);
}
```

This created a new function called `nextSong`, which when run will change the URL of the audio player to the next song in the array. How it does this is it selected the player from the ID, and sets the attribute (`attr`) `src` (source) to the entry in the songs array using the index number, then increases the index by one so that next time it displays the next song in the list.

```
$("#player").bind('ended', nextSong);
```

Here, it 'binds' the `ended` event on the audio player to the next song function. This means that when it finishes playing (the end of a song), then it runs the `nextSong` function which changes the source the the next song, and starts it playing again.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    nextSong();
});
```

All this does, is when the page is loaded it runs the `nextSong` function once to manually start it, however is probably not needed due to the `autoplay` attribute on the audio player.

---

I know there are probably more efficient ways of doing this, but I have tried to keep it as simple as possible so that the asker understands the code.